# json, wcf and fractions in string

Tags: android, wcf, json, rest

If you check my previous questions, you will see that they are all in some way related to "\" or "/" for Android and why my implementations of code wasn't working when other people's versions were.

I now know why mine wasn't working.

I am developing for a `live client` who has access to a content management system, from which I am getting the data. Other than the general checks, they can post anything they want to the site.

They are posting sizes in inches; e.g. 5-1/2

It is this, and this alone, which is screwing up my `Restful json`.

For example, 1 eigth has become

```
 1\\\/8
```

Currently, I am doing a string rewrite at the `WCF` point to catch these 'fractions' and turn them into decimal just so I can continue development. But I can't code for every eventuality and Android/Eclipse fails at `JSONArray json=new JSONArray(result);`

Would appreciate any input on this.

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched high and wide for an answer to this, and have finally found it.

I will share for anyone else experiencing the same issue:

It is the WCF Rest service.

Learning WCF and Android at the same time led me to believe that the response from WCF should be a String serialized in the Json format.

To do this, a .Net object, array or whatever would go through DataContractJsonSerializer before being returned as a String to Android for further parsing.

Something like this:

```
Dim stream1 As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
Dim ser As DataContractJsonSerializer = New DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(myType))
ser.WriteObject(stream1, myThing)
Dim _json As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream1.ToArray())
stream1.Close()
return _json
```

Wrong.

Keep your object, array or whatever and return that instead; WCF will take care of the proper escaping for you.

For example (this is VB);

IService:

```
<OperationContract()> _
<WebGet(BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate:="/MyKit/{AccountID}")> _
Function GetKit(ByVal AccountID As String) As MyKit
```

Service:

```
Public Function GetKit(ByVal AccountID As String) As MyKit Implements IService1.GetKit

    Dim allKit As New MyKit() //Your object
    objDal.CommandText = 'run some sql here - or whatever

    Using dr As SqlDataReader = "blah"

    //populate your object

    End Using

    Return allKit //return the object, not the string representation of it

End Function
```

Using DataContractJsonSerializer for sending as Json to Android from WCF effectively 'pre-escapes' the data. When it gets to Android, the Json parser is unable to handle it, because it also escapes the data.

Answer (score 0):

On reflection, and further investigation, it isn't the escaped fractions causing the problem. 
It is something more fundamental.
Will close the question.